# How to remove an Dissolved Edges without removing the Vertices?

Tags: python, modeling, edit-mode, vertices, edges

Шs it possible to adjust the removal of Dissolve Edges in the following way?
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Before the operation open up the tools panel of the 3D View.<kbd>T</kbd>
After the operation, uncheck **Dissolve Verts**.
[image]

---

**Alternatively**, remove *Only Edges and Faces* <kbd>X</kbd>, then fill in the missing faces.
[image]